# MYSQL trigger to update field based on datetime field

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need to create some sort of trigger that monitors a datetime field. If that datetime field equals current date (easier to monitor just date than date time itself) then a second field is updated. For example the following fields demonstrate:

expired   (datetime)
active    (integer)

If current date equals expired then update active to '0'. Any help with this, kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, triggers can only have a DML-action as a triggering event. That means, they get only executed when a row is inserted, updated or deleted. They **do not** monitor the current time and date. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

However, why do you need the extra field? Create a view such as:

```
create view userView as 
select userid, case when expired < now() then 1 else 0 end as active
from   user;
```

Or just include that case-statement as a computed result set column in your actual query.

Comment: the extra field is required to visually and programmatically identify records that need to be deleted. So I  guess having a separate script to check the field or execute the view will have to do. thanks for your response.